# Convert responseText object to string for alert

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get text from a .txt file, with Javascript. I am trying to test my code by using an alert statement to display the text from the file.

I am getting this alert box:

[image: example]

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Obtain services text from .txt file
    var text = new XMLHttpRequest();
    text.open("GET", "js/servText.txt", true);
    text.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // Check states 4 = Ready to parse, 200 = found file
        if(text.readyState === 4 && text.readyState === 200) {
            text = text.responseText;
        }
    }
    alert(text);
    text.send(null);
});
```

I have tried to use JSON.stringify(); but I got an alert box with '{}' and it did not work in Google Chrome.

I also tried to use toString(); and String();

Any help would be great! Thanks -Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your `alert` statement *into* the callback.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Obtain services text from .txt file
    var text = new XMLHttpRequest();
    text.open("GET", "js/servText.txt", true);
    text.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // Check states 4 = Ready to parse, 200 = found file
        if(text.readyState === 4 && text.status === 200) {
            alert(text.responseText);
        }
    }
    text.send(null);
});
```

AJAX calls are, as the name implies, Asynchronous. Your `alert` gets called *immediatly*, it doesn't wait for the AJAX request to complete.

Asynchronousness can be quite a mind boggle. Your code doesn't run from top to bottom but rather you have to look at the events. Where does an event start? what data do I have? etc.

Comment: For some reason it is not triggering the alert statement. Any ideas? Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: Oh, your `if` is weird. You'll want to check `status` for `200` instead of `readyState`.